# chronological order in subequations no alphanumerics (amsmath)

Tags: equations, amsmath

I am searching for a simple way to use `subequations`, with numerical numbering, so I don't have `(1a) (1b)` like in the example below etc. I simply want `(1) (2)` etc

Thanks for the help

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\StepSubequations{
  \stepcounter{parentequation}
  \gdef\theparentequation{\arabic{parentequation}}
  \setcounter{equation}{0}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{alignat}{2}
a&=b(x) \quad &\text{for} t<t_1  \label{eq:subeq1}\\
\StepSubequations
a&=c(x)  \quad &\text{for} t\geq t_1 \label{eq:subeq2}
\end{alignat}
\label{straincomponent}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! If  that's what you want, don't use the `subequations` environment and everything will go fine.

Comment: what would be the best option for equations with double alignment?

Comment: The second column is , so to say, a comment. What do you mean with ‘option’?

Comment: its a definition fwhich environment should i use? The function is defined by several sections

Answer (score 1):

You can have this, based on `empheq`(which loads `mathtools`) but you'll lose the possibility to refer to the definition as a whole:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left={a=\empheqlbrace}]{alignat=2}
b(x) \quad &\text{for } t<t_1 \label{eq:subeq1}
\\
c(x) \quad &\text{for } t\geq t_1 \label{eq:subeq2}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With use of the  `numcases` environment from the `cases` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cases}

\begin{document}

\begin{numcases}{a=}
  b(x) & for $t<t_1$        \label{eq:subeq1},\\
  c(x) & for $t\geq t_1$    \label{eq:subeq2}
\end{numcases}
From \eqref{eq:subeq1} folows \dots
\end{document}
```

[image]